# How to interpret the datetime parameter in Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, datetime, google-calendar-api

After proper authorization with the Google calendar api, I tried the following lines of code:

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='qeiopruweqirup@group.calendar.google.com',orderBy='updated',
  timeMin='2014-08-01T00:00:00Z',timeMax='2014-08-31T00:00:00Z',pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for event in events['items']:
    print event['summary'], event['start'], event['end']
  page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```

The code works fine except for a minor quirk in the result which I have copied below to illustrate my point:

```
FakeEvent2 {u'dateTime': u'2014-08-22T01:00:00-04:00'} {u'dateTime': u'2014-08-22T13:00:00-04:00'}
FakeEvent3 {u'dateTime': u'2014-08-27T18:00:00-04:00'} {u'dateTime': u'2014-08-28T06:00:00-04:00'}
FakeEvent1 {u'dateTime': u'2014-08-21T02:00:00-04:00'} {u'dateTime': u'2014-08-21T14:00:00-04:00'}
```

While making the request I coded the `datetime` variable in the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`. However, both the `start` and the `end` times for the events have an additional string `-04:00`. What sense should I make out of this? My guess it that it means 4 hours, but I am confused as to why Google would put it that way. For instance, I tried writing a short function to see which event is valid for the current minute. That function returns an event that is 4 hours past its end time! For example, if there's an entry in the calendar from 8 am to 9 am, that entry shows up on the query for `is there an active event during (11:45 am, 11;46 am)?`.

Why not stick to the standard way of specifying the `start` and the `end`? What's the advantage of this *A-B* way of specifying a point in time? I was not able to find the reference where I could read more about this datatype by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events list operation will give you events in the timezone offset of the calendar. If you only want to work with events returned in UTC, you can specify the timezone parameter to the list request https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Also take a look in the time definition from RFC 3339 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339 to understand the offset (-04:00)